# Define object instance properties using metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

I'm trying to use metaclass to produce a class that an object of this class has instance properties.This is the desired outcome:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._var_a = None
        self._var_b = None
```

However; I don't see how. Here is what I have:

```
# Emulate inbound
_regs = dict(Foo=dict(_var_a=None, _var_b=None))

class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct, **kwargs):
        return super(MyMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

for key, val in _regs.items():
    globals()[key] = MyMeta(key, (), val)
```

But the `val` results in class properties so each instance of `Foo` uses those versus what I'm trying to get in the desired outcome.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What's wrong with the normal way of giving an object instance attributes (like your `Foo` class)?

Comment: Creating a DSL interpreter

Comment: That's the job of `__init__` not the job of metaclass.  If you need it to be DRY, do it in a superclass or a mixin.

Comment: I ended up adding slots to the class created by metaclass...